# What happens if I backtrack before fighting the Stygian?

Tags: darksiders

On Darksiders, right before fighting the Stygian boss you can get a Vulgrim location, from which you could go back to the beginning of the Ashland.

Since the Stygian is still alive, there should be the Ash titans roaming around (they eat you instantly if you let them too close); however, at this point of the game you already have your horse and therefore you should be able to kill them.

Has anybody tried this? What happens in this case?

Comment: I have to check if I have a savegame at that point, but I'm pretty sure you're obliged to fight an ash titan before facing the Stygian. If I recall it well, it's after the arena section, in the zone with the wooden platforms where you had to stand on to avoid being eaten.

Comment: Yes, you are forced to battle an ash titan (and you get a lot of blue souls btw). But how about the open areas? Are there unlimited ash titans?

Comment: Going from memory, I believe this point in the game is inaccessible from the rest of the area - you cannot return to the outside map with Ruin, until you defeat the Stygian.